# How to deal with 'out-of-bounds' error for timestamp in the method 'pandas.read_sql()'

Tags: python, pandas, python-2.7

### Environment :

- pandas 0.20.3
- python 2.7.13

### Objective and Problem :

I'm using method **pandas.read_sql()** to retrieve the table from SQL that also contains values of invalidated timestamp (9999-12-30 23:00:00).
 But, the line of code throws the error ***'Out of bounds nanosecond timestamp : 9999-12-30 23:00:00'***.

How do i deal with parsing the timestamp in this case?

### Background :

I have checked the [pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.20/generated/pandas.read_sql.html?highlight=read_sql#pandas.read_sql) for the solution. However, it seems to have no relevant support to configure the timestamp parser.

### Code Snippet :

```py
import pyodbc as pyo
import pandas as pd
db_conn = pyo.connect('DSN=MySQL Connection 3;',autocommit=True)
tbl_df = pd.read_sql('select * from orders',db_conn)
```

I expect to either parse the cells consisting of invalidated timestamps or to avoid parsing timestamps by default.

Comment: Can't provide a concise answer because there is not an MCVE in the question.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples

Answer (score 0):

In 0.20.3 `pandas.read_sql()` has `parse_dates : list or dict, default: None`

So it would be unexpected that pandas is parsing the date found in your database.

Remove `select * from orders` to `select col1, ..., datecol from orders` and eliminate `datecol`. What happens?

Change `datecol` to `UNIX_TIMESTAMP(STR_TO_DATE(datecol, '%M %d %Y %h:%i'))` so that you can pull the data in as a non-datetime formate.  From there, you can convert in Pandas.